# Where can I get the files to install f2c on redhat linux?

Tags: linux, fortran, fortran77

I am looking for an rpm or simple install instructions for getting f2c to work on my redhat linux os. I am new to linux and it is difficult finding something like this on google.

(The goal is to use f2c to convert a simple fortran77 file to c, then compile)

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

1. Getting the source with rsync (recommended):

   ```
   $ rsync -avz netlib.org::netlib/f2c/src f2c
   ```

   Getting the sources via FTP:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p f2c/src
   $ cd f2c/src
   $ ftp ftp.netlib.org
   ftp> cd f2c
   ftp> prompt
   ftp> mget *
   ```
2. To build the sources, in the f2c/src directory do:

   ```
   $ make -f makefile.u
   ```
3. To install the binary, copy it to a directory in your $PATH:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/man/man1
   $ cp f2c /usr/local/bin
   $ cp f2c.1t /usr/local/man/man1
   ```
4. To compile Fortran programs you will also need [libf2c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libf2c.zip):

   ```
   $ mkdir libf2c
   $ cd libf2c
   $ unzip ../libf2c.zip
   $ make -f makefile.u
   $ make -f makefile.u install LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib
   ```

   libf2c is a combination of the [libF77](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libf77) and [libI77](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libi77) libraries. You can install these libraries separately and then link with "-lF77 -lI77". Assuming f2c/src is available from the current directory, save [libF77](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libf77) and [libI77](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libi77) and do the following (not necessary if you have already installed libf2c above):

   ```
   $ sh libf77
   $ sh libi77
   $ cd libF77
   $ make CFLAGS=-I../f2c/src
   $ make install LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib
   $ cd ../libI77
   $ make CFLAGS=-I../f2c/src
   $ make install LIBDIR=/usr/local/lib
   ```
5. The [fc shell script](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/fc) is a nice frontend to use with f2c. Save it somewhere and do:

   ```
   $ cp fc /usr/local/bin/f77
   $ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/f77
   ```

   I renamed it to f77 to avoid conflicts, since fc is a bash builtin. The fc script expects libf2c rather than libF77 and libI77, so you have to edit it and replace "-lf2c" with "-lF77 -lI77" if you have installed these libraries instead of libf2c above.
6. Finally, to compile your program you can do:

   ```
   $ f77 source.f -o binary
   ```

Also check out the [f2c parent directory](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/). It contains [getopt.c](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/getopt.c), [f2c.pdf](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/f2c.pdf) and some other stuff that may be useful.

For more further information about f2c consult the readme (<kbd>less f2c/src/readme</kbd>) and the manpage (<kbd>man f2c</kbd>). For further information about the fc script look at the comments at the beginning of the file.

Comment: wow. that's an incredible answer! thanks! i got it to install. However, when i run "f77 source.f -o binary", i get this error: "error: f2c.h: No such file or directory". Do you know what I am doing wrong? (I installed libf2c according to your first set of instructions)

Comment: You can try *"f77 -I f2c/src source.f -o binary"*, where f2c/src is the directory that contains the f2c sources (including f2c.h). Copying f2c.h into /usr/local/include should make this permanent.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a precompiled f2c package from ATrpms: http://atrpms.net/name/f2c/
It does include both the headers (such as `f2c.h`) and the library (`libf2c`) in standard directories, so you shouldn't have any trouble compiling after that.

Otherwise, you could try to compile directly with a free Fortran compiler; try `gfortran`. If not installed, it's in package `gcc-gfortran`, so you can install it with the command: `yum install gcc-gfortran`.