# Can't compile and link library

Tags: gcc, fortran, fortran77, f2c

I try to use a library compiled with gcc called [matlisp](http://matlisp.sourceforge.net/) based on fortran code. After specifyng the f77 compiler, I could performed the autoreconf, configure and make command to obtain the file libmatlisp.so.

But when I try to use it i get a:

```
 Error opening shared object ".../libmatlisp.so":
 /usr/lib/libf2c.so.2: undefined symbol: MAIN__.
```

And when i perform the command ld libmatlisp.so i get:

```
...
libmatlisp.so: undefined reference to `idamax_'
libmatlisp.so: undefined reference to `dger_'
/usr/lib/libf2c.so.2: undefined reference to `MAIN__'
libmatlisp.so: undefined reference to `zscal_'
libmatlisp.so: undefined reference to `dscal_'
....
```

Is there a way to improve the situation?

I already try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345725/linker-errors-with-fortran-to-c-library-usr-lib-libf2c-so-undefined-referenc) solution but it does not work.

I also try to change the compiler to gfortran but i get some some run time error messages mentionning missing libraries that are part of libf2c.

Comment: Hello, do not use version tags without the generic one. Much smaller number of pople subscribe to `fortran77` than to `fortran`.

Comment: How exactly did you apply the referenced accepted answer (reinstall f2c and start again) and how exactly it did not work? Did write some error message?

Comment: And what command did you run when you "But when I try to use it i get a:"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I move to a more recent source of matlisp 2012 instead of 2003, and it run properly in my environment now.